# How can I check if a SQL Server constraint exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[webpages_Roles_UserProfiles_Target]', 'xxxxx') IS NOT NULL
   DROP CONSTRAINT [dbo].[webpages_Roles_UserProfiles_Target]
```

I want to be able to check if there is a constraint existing before I drop it. I use the code above with a type of 'U' for tables.

How could I modify the code above (change the xxxx) to make it check for the existence of the constraint ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
 SELECT
    * 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
```

or else try this

```
  SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NameofConstraint,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName,
OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TableName,
type_desc AS ConstraintType
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT'
```

or

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.TableName'))
 BEGIN 
ALTER TABLE TableName DROP CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINTNAME 
END
```

Comment: If the table have PK, Do something like this IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sysobjects  WHERE xtype = 'PK' AND parent_obj = OBJECT_ID('Tablename'))
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE Tablename DROP CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINTNAME 
END

Answer (score 9):

Try something like this

```
IF OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('constraint_name'), 'IsConstraint') = 1
    ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name
```

Comment: IF OBJECT_ID('Schema.keyname') IS NULL
    ALTER TABLE Schema.tablename ADD CONSTRAINT keyname...

Comment: @MartinB Yes, this looks like a nice shortcut for `ADD CONSTRAINT`! For `DROP CONSTRAINT` skipping `IsConstraint` check risks `ALTER TABLE` failure as the `OBJECT_ID` will return non-null if 'Schema.keyname' is an index or a table.

Answer (score 4):

you can do something like :

```
IF EXISTS
     (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[CONSTRAINT_NAME]') 
      AND type in  (N'U'))

BEGIN
....
END
ELSE
```

Comment: `type in  (N'U')` checks for the existence of a table [not a constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx)

Comment: right Martin. Should not include (N'U') for constraint checking.

Comment: type in (N'UQ') would be correct for checking the type of a unique constraint.